# Image overlapping in react native

Tags: react-native

I am using absolute position to overlap a component over an image. There is another component after it which is a view with an orange colored background. It goes behind the absolute positioned component. How can keep it after the absolute positioned component (the height of this component might vary so I cannot use margin or height etc here)?
Have a look at the snack: https://snack.expo.io/@codebyte99/overlap-test

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
       <Image
          source={{
            uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/logo-og.png',
            cache: 'only-if-cached',
          }}
          style={{width: 400, height: 100}}
        />

        <View style={styles.overlap}>
          <Text>Event1</Text>
          <Text>Event2</Text>
          <Text>Event3</Text>
          <Text>Event4</Text>
          <Text>Event5</Text>
          <Text>Event6</Text>
          <Text>Event7</Text>
        </View>

        <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'orange', height: 200, width: 500 }}/>

      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  overlap: {
    width: 300, 
    backgroundColor: 'red', 
    borderColor: 'red', 
    borderWidth: 1,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 80,
    zIndex: 9999,
    overflow: 'visible'
  },
});
```

How it looks now:

[image]

what I want:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do the orange and red box in one container and set this to an absolute position:

```
<View style={{position: "absolute", flexDirection:"column"}}
     <View style={styles.YourStyleWithoutPositionAbsolute}>
          <Text>Event1</Text>
          <Text>Event2</Text>
          <Text>Event3</Text>
          <Text>Event4</Text>
          <Text>Event5</Text>
          <Text>Event6</Text>
          <Text>Event7</Text>
        </View>

   <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'orange', height: 200, width: 500 }}/>
</View>
```